# Fastest way to double the length of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
[1,2,3,4,5].duplicate(); // [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Maybe something like:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
array.push(array);
```

But what's the fastest method?

Comment: You don't simply mean "double the length", right? You want to replicate the contents of the array, it looks like.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's correct.

Comment: When I have two methods of achieving the same thing I look to https://jsperf.com/ to run my own tests. It is a good tool for benchmarking.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and replace the original array with the new one:

```js
array = array.concat(array);
```

Or [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (modifies the original array):

```js
[].push.apply(array, array);
```

Or [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (modifies the original array):

```js
array.push(...array);
```

Comment: The concat method doesn't appear to be working (at least in Chrome dev tools).

Comment: In Chrome devtools, `var array = [1,2,3]; array = array.concat(array);` returns `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @Oriol You don't need to assign the concat result to array again, just doig this `array.concat(array);` will perform the same thing as `array = array.concat(array);`

Comment: This won't modify the original. Overwriting it won't either.

Comment: @Magicprog.fr But `concat` does not alter the original array, so I replace it with the new one. `push` modifies the original array.

Comment: @Oriol ok thanks for explaining this, i didn't knew it.

Answer (score 3):

The **FASTEST** way to do something in JS is usually using simple C-like native statements.

I think this will be the fastest one:

```
function duplicate(arr) {
      for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++)
            arr[i+len]=arr[i];
}
```

A slower but more elegant one would be this:

```
arr=arr.concat(arr);
```

Or this one:

```
[].push.apply(arr,arr);
```

**EcmaScript 6** also allows you to do the same using the [spread operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn919259%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). This operator just puts all the values of the array for you in the place you have written it, so this `var arr = [0,1,2,3];console.log(...arr)` turns into `var arr = [0,1,2,3];console.log(0,1,2,3)`.

```
arr.push(...arr);
```

However, EcmaScript 6 **is not yet widely supported** (and this feature neither) so if I were you I wouldn't use it. Although ES 6 has just been approved & released (as **@LyeFish** said in the comments) most of browsers are still working on it.

> EcmaScript-262 6th edition officially released 5 days ago (thanks to @LyeFish)!
>   http://www.ecma-international.org/news/index.html

Comment: @vinayakj: All these answers use native JavaScript.

Comment: @vinayakj right. Although their performance is very similar in most cases, depending on the implementation and the length of the array, the first one could be the fastest.

Comment: Nice note on ES6. The ES6 features are no longer experimental since the spec has been finalized and accepted. https://esdiscuss.org/topic/ecmascript-2015-is-now-an-ecma-standard

Answer (score 0):

According to my test results, the winners are `concat` followed by `push` methods.  I also tested looping method and my own newly-introduced `splice` routine.

Here's the testing "infrastructure" code that was used:

```
var toArray = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

Function.prototype.testerTimes = function(number) {
    var func = this;
    return function() {
        var args = toArray(arguments), i = 0;
        for( ; i < number; func.apply(this, args), i++);
    };
};

Function.prototype.testerTime = function(units) {
    var func = this;
    return function() {
        var start = Date.now(), diff;
        func.apply(this, toArray(arguments));
        diff = Date.now() - start;
        return units === "s" ? diff / 1000 : units === "m" ? diff / 60000 : units === "h" ? diff / 3600000 : diff;
    };
};

Function.prototype.testerToConsole = function(prefix, message) {
    var func = this;
    return function() {
        console.log(prefix + message + func.apply(this, toArray(arguments)));    
    };
};

Function.prototype.makeTestReady = function(times, units, prefix, message) {
    return this.testerTimes(times).testerTime(units).testerToConsole(prefix, message);
};
```

Here's the test code:

```
function genArray(num) {
    for(var i = 0, arr = []; i < num; arr.push(++i));
    return arr;
};

var numberOfRuns = 1000000;
var timeUnit = "s";
var messagePrefix = "   ";

var funcs = [
    function duplicateConcat(arr) {
        var arrCopy = arr.slice(0);
        return arrCopy.concat(arrCopy);    
    },

    function duplicatePush(arr) {
        var arrCopy = arr.slice(0);
        arrCopy.push.apply(arrCopy, arrCopy);
        return arrCopy;
    },

    function duplicateLoop(arr) {
        var arrCopy = arr.slice(0);
        for(var i = 0, len = arrCopy.length; i < len; i++) {
            arrCopy[len + i] = arrCopy[i]; 
        }    
        return arrCopy;
    },

    function duplicateSplice(arr) {
        var arrCopy = arr.slice(0);
        arrCopy.splice.apply(arrCopy, [arrCopy.length, 0].concat(arrCopy));
        return arrCopy;
    }
].map(function(func, index, arr) {
    return func.makeTestReady(numberOfRuns, timeUnit, messagePrefix, func.name + ": ");
});

for(var i = 5; i < 25; i+= 5) {
    console.log(i + "-element array:");
    funcs.forEach(function(func) {
        func(genArray(i));
    });
}
```

And, here are the results of 1,000,000 runs of each function for arrays of sizes 5, 10, 15, and 20:

```
5-element array: 
   duplicateConcat: 0.236  
   duplicatePush: 0.228 
   duplicateLoop: 0.372 
   duplicateSplice: 0.45
10-element array: 
   duplicateConcat: 0.241  
   duplicatePush: 0.273    
   duplicateLoop: 0.433 
   duplicateSplice: 0.48  
15-element array:
   duplicateConcat: 0.261 
   duplicatePush: 0.293
   duplicateLoop: 0.5
   duplicateSplice: 0.522 
20-element array: 
   duplicateConcat: 0.24 
   duplicatePush: 0.311
   duplicateLoop: 0.602 
   duplicateSplice: 0.558
```

Comment: Just a reminder that with `.apply()`, doing `toArray(arguments)` is unnecessary. The `.apply()` method since ECMAScript 3 has been  specified to accept both native Arrays and Arguments objects. ECMAScript 5 then expanded its definition. That said... comparing `.concat()` and `.push.apply` seems a little pointless since they do two different things. No one is going to do a `array.slice(0)` followed by a `.push.apply` because a single `.concat()` would have the same effect.

Comment: `toArray()` was used for backward compatibility reasons, just in case somebody is using an older browser or older version of node.  The `arr.slice(0)` was necessary for the `push` version because otherwise the array just keeps growing and you overflow the stack.  The `arr.slice(0)` statement was added to every function to make sure that they are equivalent except their own unique implementations of duplication.  This was done to assure that performance metrics are not biased.

Comment: Yes, I understand the need for `arr.slice(0)` given your setup. I'm just saying that even without that, comparing the two approaches are comparing two different things (as opposed to different approaches to the same thing). As for old browsers, it would require something like IE5 before you hit compatibility issues. I'd be surprised if SO even renders.

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you.  Yes, they are different approaches.  `concat` returns a new array, whereas `push` adds elements to the existing one.  Which method is more efficient to duplicate an array on "itself?"  Time-wise, concatenation is a bit faster.

Comment: Point is that if once needs to mutate the original, they'd not use `.concat()` and so its performance benefits wouldn't be relevant. And if one doesn't want to mutate, then they'd never use `.push.apply()`.

Comment: Yes, of course.  My post simply focused on performance of functions that take an array, copy it, modify the copy towards the same result yet using a different method, and return the copy.  How a developer uses this information is outside the scope of my entry.